# Is $\{(x_1, x_2,x_3) \in \mathbf F^3 \mid x_1+2x_2+3x_3=4\}$ a subspace of $\mathbf F^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I found that there is more than one additive identity for this set. For example, $(0,2,0) \in \mathbf F^3$, and if $(x,y,z)\in\mathbf F^3$, then
$$x+2y+3z+0+2(2)+3(0)=4+4$$
$$\implies x+2y+3z=4$$
So, $(x,y,z)+(0,2,0)=(x,y,z)$. So, $(0,2,0)$ is an additive identity.

However, $(x,y,z)+(4,0,0)=(x,y,z)$. So, $(4,0,0)$ is also an additive identity but $(0,2,0) \ne (4,0,0)$.

Is this justification that this set is not a vector space?

Comment: Neither $(0, 2, 0)$ nor $(4, 0, 0)$ is an additive identity, and I don't understand why you think they are. Also, what is $\mathbf{F}$?

Comment: $\mathbf F$ is a field. Why isn't $(0,2,0)$ an additive identity?

Comment: Well, $(x, y, z) + (0, 2, 0) = (x, y + 2, z) \neq (x, y, z)$ unless the field has characteristic $2$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Don't we check using the conditions defined in the set?

Comment: A vector space has a unique additive identity, in this case $(0, 0, 0)$. A subspace has the *same* additive identity. If you're trying to show that a subset of a vector space is a subspace, you use the conditions defining the subset to check if the additive identity of the vector space belongs to the subset.

Comment: No. You write the set element in that form. You do not plug in $(0,2,0)$ to that form. You note that $(0,2,0)$ is of that for ($y=1$) and therefore is in the set

Comment: I am sorry. I wrote the wrong set. EDITED.

Comment: Even with the new question, I see that $(0,0,0)$ is still the unique additive identity of $\mathbf F^3$ and $(0,0,0)$ is not in the set in question.

Comment: As the additive identity doesn't belong to the subset, the subset is not a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

This subset *is* a subspace of $\Bbb F^3$. The most efficient way to see this is to note that 
$$
S=\bigl\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb F^3:x_1+2\,x_2+3\,x_3=0\bigr\}
$$
is the nullspace of the matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\end{bmatrix}
$$
Since the nullspace of an $m\times n$ matrix [is a subspace](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Null_Space_is_Subspace) of $\Bbb F^n$ the result is immediate.

Of course, the additive identity here is $\mathbf 0=(0,0,0)$.

Your claim that $(0,2,0)$ is an additive identity here is incorrect if $\Bbb F$ does not have characteristic two. In fact, $(0,2,0)\notin S$ unless $\Bbb F$ has characteristic two.

Also, note that $(2,-1,0)\in S$ and $(2,-1,0)+(0,2,0)=(2,1,0)$. But
$$
2+2(1)+3(0)=4\neq0
$$
So your argument fails.

Comment: What would be the additive identity?

Comment: $\mathbf 0$ of course!

Comment: Damn, I'm sorry. I must edit my question. I goofed.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out the if $\mathbb{F}$ has characteristic $2$, then $S$ is a subspace.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Is this not clear?

Comment: You said that $(0, 2, 0) \in S$ if the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}$ is $2$, but I don't think it's clear that $S$ is a subspace. In particular, in the case $\operatorname{char}\mathbb{F} = 2$, we have $S = \{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{F}^3 \mid x_1 + x_3 = 0\}$ whereas for $\operatorname{char}\mathbb{F} \neq 2$, $S$ is not a subspace.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Meh the answer's fine. Nitpick at best.